# Is it possible to have duplicate entries for "username" in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In our Symfony2 app, we have a class named `sfGuardUser` extending from `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User`(part of the FOSUserBundle package). So it inherits the $username field from that User class which throws an error when I try to insert a duplicate username. What I'm trying to do is to check whether a user confirmed his/her phone number and email address before throwing that error.

For example when someone registered with username "Anna" but didn't confirm her email and phone number. Someone else should be able to register with the username "Anna". How should I implement this behavior?

I tried to do [attribute override](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) without any success. Here's the code:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="sfGuard\Bundle\sfGuardBundle\Entity\sfGuardUserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="sf_guard_user")
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *     @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="email",
 *          column=@ORM\Column(
 *              name     = "email_address",
 *              type     = "string",
 *              length   = 250,
 *              unique   = true
 *          )
 *      ),
 *      @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="username",
 *          column=@ORM\Column(
 *              name     = "username",
 *              type     = "string",
 *              length   = 250,
 *              unique   = false
 *          )
 *      ),
 *      @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="enabled",
 *          column=@ORM\Column(
 *              name     = "is_active",
 *              type     = "boolean",
 *              nullable = true,
 *              options  = {
 *                  "default" : 1
 *              }
 *          )
 *      )
 * })
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class sfGuardUser extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min = 2,
     *     minMessage = "Too short."
     * )
     */
    protected $firstName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the answere

```
<?php
namespace LoginBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
/**
 * Contacts
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Contacts")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="LoginBundle\Repository\ContactsRepository")
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *     @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="username",
 *          column=@ORM\Column(
 *              nullable = true
 *          )
 *      ),
 *     @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="usernameCanonical",
 *          column=@ORM\Column(
 *              name = "username_canonical",
 *              nullable = true
 *          )
 *      ),
 *     @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="email",
 *          column=@ORM\Column(
 *              nullable = true
 *          )
 *      ),
 *     @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="emailCanonical",
 *          column=@ORM\Column(
 *              name = "email_canonical",
 *              nullable = true
 *          )
 *      )
 * })
 */
class Contacts extends BaseUser
{ 
   /**
    * @var int
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
   protected $id;
   /**
    * @var int
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="Type", type="integer",nullable=true)
    */
   protected $type;
   /**
    * Get id
    *
    * @return integer
    */
   public function getId()
   {
    return $this->id;
   }
  /**
   * Set type
   *
   * @param integer $type
   * @return Contacts
   */
  public function setType($type)
   {
     $this->type = $type;
     return $this;
   }
 /**
  * Get type
  *
  * @return integer
  */
 public function getType()
  {
    return $this->type;
  }
}
```

Aslo refer this post [attribute overrides for username fosuserbundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/982)